# Azure Blob Storage downloading ORC files in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

It is my first time using Azure Storage and ORC.

Here is what I have learned so far, I able to download a ORC blob storage file from Azure and save to disk. Once download complete, I can iterate ORC file using **pyorc** library in Python. They are mostly smaller files and can easily fit into memory. My question is, instead of writing to a file, I would like to keep the blob in memory and iterate and can avoid writing to a disk. I can download the blob into stream but I am not sure how to use **pyorc** with blob stream or I cannot locate the help for it.

I appreciate any help and best practice for azure storage download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank Jim Xu for his solution and I slightly modify his solution to fit to my need if anyone interested

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, BlobClient
from io import BytesIO
import pyorc

containerClient = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(azureConnString, container_name=azureContainer)
blobList = containerClient.list_blobs(azureBlobFolder)
for fileNo, blob in enumerate(blobList):
    blobClient = containerClient.get_blob_client(blob=blob.name)
    with BytesIO() as f:
        blobClient.download_blob().readinto(f)
        reader = pyorc.Reader(f)
        print(next(reader))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

```
import pyorc
import io

from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

key = 'account key'

blob_client = BlobClient(account_url='https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net',
                         container_name='test',
                         blob_name='my.orc',
                         credential=key,)

with io.BytesIO() as f:
    blob_client.download_blob().readinto(f)
    reader = pyorc.Reader(f)
    print(next(reader))
```

[image]